# How do I use my existing KeePass database on my new iPad without iTunes on a computer?

Tags: itunes, ipad, unix, sandbox

I'm a Linux user who bought an iPad. I'm also an Infosec pro who uses the KeePassX password manager. All my passwords are too long to type on the iPad - so I want to use my password manager on iPad. I installed MiniKeePass on the iPad - and with some difficulty (had to type in the password for one service), moved the database (.kdbx) to iPad. I used the export/share functionality to make the kdbx to make it available to MiniKeePass app.

I'm stuck here. I need to move my Key File too.

I can't find any way to get the Key File into MiniKeePass. The standard export/share functions don't seem to work for plain text files without extensions.

All the advice I got so far is "Use iTunes". I'm a Linux user; no Windows / Mac or even Wine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you contacted KeePass support to ask them how to do what you want?

Comment: Ah, an OpenSource enthusiast mistake. I (probably wrongly) assumed the only support would be community support. I'll check. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I opened an issue on their repo https://github.com/MiniKeePass/MiniKeePass/issues/493 - waiting for response. [edit: Apparently this is the normal method to ask for and get support.]

Comment: @fsb I'm holding out with some hope in this pull request - still under testing - https://github.com/MiniKeePass/MiniKeePass/pull/389
It seems to reflect some of my predicament.

Comment: Looks like I need to wait longer for this to be resolved. I'll post an update when there's any progress.

Comment: You could try with an "iOS File Explorer" like Documents5 (https://readdle.com/products/documents). Store temporally the Key File there (you can transfer the key file using the built-in http transfer system). Once you have the key file on the app try to transfer to MiniKeePass app using the share menu.

Answer (score 1):

The key file has a file extension: `.key`

I tested the following with Dropbox and an iPad running iOS 11. I deleted my existing key file for the test:

1. rename your key file with a .key extension
2. move the newly renamed key file to a shared folder in a cloud (or anything that the iPad can also access)
3. on your iPad, open the app for the folder share and find the key file
4. export the key file ...
5. one of the options should be "Open In..." tap it
6. you should get a list of apps you can copy the key file to and one of them should be MiniKeePass, tap it
7. this opens MiniKeePass with the key file listed under "Key Files"

That should work. Again, I did this from Dropbox, so another folder sharing service might behave differently.